# Dojo custom language variants

Tags: dojo, internationalization

Does Dojo support creation of custom language variants to be used for with Dojo's locale and i18n

Does anyone know if I am able to create a custom language variant for Dojo's locale that works with i18n?.

```
Example

define({
   root: {
     greeting: "Hello, world!"
   }
  "de-myVariant" : true
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it can be done. If you have `nls/SampleApp.js` as:

```
define({
   root: {
     greeting: "Hello!"
   }
  "de" : true,
  "de-at": true,
  "de-x-mundl": true
});
```

then there would be three sub-directories under `nls`:

```
nls/de
nls/de-at
nls/de-x-mundl
```

for `nls/de/SampleApp.js`:

```
define(({
    greeting: "Hallo!"
}));
```

for `nls/de-at/SampleApp.js`:

```
define(({
    greeting: "Gruß Gott!"
}));
```

and for `nls/de-x-mundl/SampleApp.js`:

```
define(({
    greeting: "Servus, Mundi!"
}));
```

Then if you config Dojo to get the locale as a URL parameter:

```
<script src="./dojo/1.8.3/dojo/dojo.js" 
        data-dojo-config="locale: location.search.substring(1).toLowerCase()">
</script>
```

you can switch the language easily by passing the locale tag as that parameter:

```
   .../app.html?de-DE
   .../app.html?de-at
   .../app.html?de-x-Mundl
```

Note that Dojo considers locale tags as case-sensitive and that's why the input is `toLowerCase()`ed and internally all the tags are kept in lower-case.