# Dojo: Set locale by URL-Parameter

Tags: dojo, locale, url-parameters, boilerplate

In the Dojo Toolkit, the locale (language) has to be defined in the configuration used at loading time.

E.g.

```
<script data-dojo-config="async: 1, isDebug: 1, locale: 'es'" src="dojo/dojo.js"></script>
```

I want to specify the locale by an URL-Parameter like this:

```
../myapp/index.html?lang=es
```

I use the boilerplate for Dojo:
[Dojo Boilerplate](https://github.com/csnover/dojo-boilerplate)

One idea was to load the dojo.js this way:

```
<script data-dojo-config="async: 1, isDebug: 1, locale: function(){//Code returning the value of the language URL-Parameter}" src="dojo/dojo.js"></script>
```

But this is not working.

Thank you!

PS:
A solution is presented in [Custom language variants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16095430/dojo-custom-language-variants). But this works only, if you have only one URL-Parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work:
[URL-Parameters with JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11582512/how-to-get-url-parameters-with-javascript).

Resulting in

```
<script data-dojo-config="async: 1, isDebug: 1, locale: decodeURIComponent((new RegExp('[?|&]' + 'lang' + '=' + '([^&;]+?)(&|#|;|$)').exec(location.search)||[,''])[1].replace(/\+/g, '%20'))||null" src="dojo/dojo.js"></script>
```

Where 'lang' is the name of my Language URL-Parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that you already have a (valid) answer. But if your goal is to test a website using a specific locale, then you could just remove the `locale` property from your Dojo config and use the browser locale as an alternative.

The browser locale depends on the language you have configured in your browser.

Comment: I have to implement switch language buttons. You know the flags on some sites, changing the language. Besides I want to save the selected language if the user stores the actual URL in a bookmark. Reloading the bookmark, the language would be loaded according to the saved bookmark, because the language is saved in an URL-Parameter.